# Not enabling verbose kernel output causes windbg to not print my dbgprints in my kernel driver?

Tags: kernel, windbg, wdk, debugview

The problem with turning on verbose kernel output on debugview is that it prints loads of garbage when i attach my windbg to the system, like its too much noise.

and if i don't turn it on, my debug messages don't get printed in windows 7+ (unlike older systems where there is no such thing as verbose output)

what should i do?

by garbage i mean stuff like this gets printed in windbg a LOT (from SXS.DLL) :

```
SXS.DLL: Read 896 bytes from XML stream; HRESULT returned = 0x00000000
   00000000: 3c-3f-78-6d-6c-20-76-65-72-73-69-6f-6e-3d-22-31 (<?xml version="1)
   00000010: 2e-30-22-20-65-6e-63-6f-64-69-6e-67-3d-22-55-54 (.0" encoding="UT)
   00000020: 46-2d-38-22-20-73-74-61-6e-64-61-6c-6f-6e-65-3d (F-8" standalone=)
   00000030: 22-79-65-73-22-3f-3e-0d-0a-3c-21-2d-2d-20-43-6f ("yes"?>..<!-- Co)
   00000040: 70-79-72-69-67-68-74-20-28-63-29-20-4d-69-63-72 (pyright (c) Micr)
   00000050: 6f-73-6f-66-74-20-43-6f-72-70-6f-72-61-74-69-6f (osoft Corporatio)
   00000060: 6e-20-2d-2d-3e-0d-0a-3c-61-73-73-65-6d-62-6c-79 (n -->..<assembly)
   00000070: 20-78-6d-6c-6e-73-3d-22-75-72-6e-3a-73-63-68-65 ( xmlns="urn:sche)
   00000080: 6d-61-73-2d-6d-69-63-72-6f-73-6f-66-74-2d-63-6f (mas-microsoft-co)
   00000090: 6d-3a-61-73-6d-2e-76-31-22-20-6d-61-6e-69-66-65 (m:asm.v1" manife)
   000000a0: 73-74-56-65-72-73-69-6f-6e-3d-22-31-2e-30-22-3e (stVersion="1.0">)
   000000b0: 0d-0a-3c-61-73-73-65-6d-62-6c-79-49-64-65-6e-74 (..<assemblyIdent)
   000000c0: 69-74-79-0d-0a-20-20-20-20-76-65-72-73-69-6f-6e (ity..    version)
   000000d0: 3d-22-35-2e-31-2e-30-2e-30-22-0d-0a-20-20-20-20 (="5.1.0.0"..    )
   000000e0: 70-72-6f-63-65-73-73-6f-72-41-72-63-68-69-74-65 (processorArchite)
   000000f0: 63-74-75-72-65-3d-22-78-38-36-22-0d-0a-20-20-20 (cture="x86"..   )
   00000100: 20-6e-61-6d-65-3d-22-4d-69-63-72-6f-73-6f-66-74 ( name="Microsoft)
   00000110: 2e-57-69-6e-64-6f-77-73-2e-46-69-6c-65-53-79-73 (.Windows.FileSys)
   00000120: 74-65-6d-2e-43-4d-44-22-0d-0a-20-20-20-20-74-79 (tem.CMD"..    ty)
   00000130: 70-65-3d-22-77-69-6e-33-32-22-0d-0a-2f-3e-0d-0a (pe="win32"../>..)
   00000140: 3c-64-65-73-63-72-69-70-74-69-6f-6e-3e-57-69-6e (<description>Win)
   00000150: 64-6f-77-73-20-43-6f-6d-6d-61-6e-64-20-50-72-6f (dows Command Pro)
   00000160: 63-65-73-73-6f-72-3c-2f-64-65-73-63-72-69-70-74 (cessor</descript)
   00000170: 69-6f-6e-3e-0d-0a-0d-0a-3c-74-72-75-73-74-49-6e (ion>....<trustIn)
   00000180: 66-6f-20-78-6d-6c-6e-73-3d-22-75-72-6e-3a-73-63 (fo xmlns="urn:sc)
   00000190: 68-65-6d-61-73-2d-6d-69-63-72-6f-73-6f-66-74-2d (hemas-microsoft-)
   000001a0: 63-6f-6d-3a-61-73-6d-2e-76-33-22-3e-0d-0a-20-20 (com:asm.v3">..  )
   000001b0: 20-20-3c-73-65-63-75-72-69-74-79-3e-0d-0a-20-20 (  <security>..  )
   000001c0: 20-20-20-20-20-20-3c-72-65-71-75-65-73-74-65-64 (      <requested)
   000001d0: 50-72-69-76-69-6c-65-67-65-73-3e-0d-0a-20-20-20 (Privileges>..   )
   000001e0: 20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-3c-72-65-71-75-65-73 (         <reques)
   000001f0: 74-65-64-45-78-65-63-75-74-69-6f-6e-4c-65-76-65 (tedExecutionLeve)
   00000200: 6c-0d-0a-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20 (l..             )
   00000210: 20-20-20-6c-65-76-65-6c-3d-22-61-73-49-6e-76-6f (   level="asInvo)
   00000220: 6b-65-72-22-0d-0a-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20 (ker"..          )
   00000230: 20-20-20-20-20-20-75-69-41-63-63-65-73-73-3d-22 (      uiAccess=")
   00000240: 66-61-6c-73-65-22-0d-0a-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20 (false"..        )
   00000250: 20-20-20-20-2f-3e-0d-0a-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20 (    />..        )
   00000260: 3c-2f-72-65-71-75-65-73-74-65-64-50-72-69-76-69 (</requestedPrivi)
   00000270: 6c-65-67-65-73-3e-0d-0a-20-20-20-20-3c-2f-73-65 (leges>..    </se)
   00000280: 63-75-72-69-74-79-3e-0d-0a-3c-2f-74-72-75-73-74 (curity>..</trust)
   00000290: 49-6e-66-6f-3e-0d-0a-3c-61-70-70-6c-69-63-61-74 (Info>..<applicat)
   000002a0: 69-6f-6e-20-20-78-6d-6c-6e-73-3d-22-75-72-6e-3a (ion  xmlns="urn:)
   000002b0: 73-63-68-65-6d-61-73-2d-6d-69-63-72-6f-73-6f-66 (schemas-microsof)
   000002c0: 74-2d-63-6f-6d-3a-61-73-6d-2e-76-33-22-3e-0d-0a (t-com:asm.v3">..)
   000002d0: 20-20-20-20-3c-77-69-6e-64-6f-77-73-53-65-74-74 (    <windowsSett)
   000002e0: 69-6e-67-73-3e-0d-0a-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-3c (ings>..        <)
   000002f0: 64-70-69-41-77-61-72-65-20-20-78-6d-6c-6e-73-3d (dpiAware  xmlns=)
   00000300: 22-68-74-74-70-3a-2f-2f-73-63-68-65-6d-61-73-2e ("http://schemas.)
   00000310: 6d-69-63-72-6f-73-6f-66-74-2e-63-6f-6d-2f-53-4d (microsoft.com/SM)
   00000320: 49-2f-32-30-30-35-2f-57-69-6e-64-6f-77-73-53-65 (I/2005/WindowsSe)
   00000330: 74-74-69-6e-67-73-22-3e-74-72-75-65-3c-2f-64-70 (ttings">true</dp)
   00000340: 69-41-77-61-72-65-3e-0d-0a-20-20-20-20-3c-2f-77 (iAware>..    </w)
   00000350: 69-6e-64-6f-77-73-53-65-74-74-69-6e-67-73-3e-0d (indowsSettings>.)
   00000360: 0a-3c-2f-61-70-70-6c-69-63-61-74-69-6f-6e-3e-0d (.</application>.)
   00000370: 0a-3c-2f-61-73-73-65-6d-62-6c-79-3e-0d-0a-0d-0a (.</assembly>....)
```

Answer (score 0):

try [.ofilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-ofilter--filter-target-output-) in windbg to filter only your programs dbgprints

or try [.ocommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-ocommand--expect-commands-from-target-) tosend a specialized dbg prints

Comment: How to filter  SXS.DLL outputs using ofilter or ocommand? i only want to filter SXS.DLL outputs